# How to count values within a range in my MySQL table

Tags: mysql, count, mariadb, range

Hello i im trying to count the values within each range e.g. between 115000 - 120000 in my DURATION_IN_MS column.

my column looks like this:

```
119631
120689
143498
119798
```

```
WITH tab1 AS(
SELECT TOP 30 * 
FROM MACHINE_PROCESSING_DURATION_EVALUATION
WHERE START_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2022-11.10 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-11.10 22:00:00.000')


SELECT(
  case 
    when DURATION_IN_MS BETWEEN 115000 AND 120000 THEN '115000-120000'
    when DURATION_IN_MS BETWEEN 120000 AND 125000 THEN '120000-125000'
    else 'OTHERS'
    END) AS DURATION_IN_MS, 
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
from tab1
GROUP BY DURATION_IN_MS
```

```
my output is like this: 


[enter image description here][1]

however, for the range 115000-120000 i wanted to  show the count of 8
for the range 120000-125000 i wanted to  show the count of 6

Can someone help me ?
```

Comment: `TOP` is SQL Server syntax; have you tagged your question correctly.

Comment: do you really want 120000 counted as both in the range before it and the range after it?   normally you would make ranges like '120000-124999' or '120001-125000'

Comment: what does `select @@version;` show?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for trying to show a question. The column you describe doesn't match the description of counts. Please also don't include images, text is much better.

Answer (score 0):

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_6UyPwrZ)

```
SELECT
  case 
      when DURATION_IN_MS BETWEEN 115000 AND 120000 THEN '115000-120000'
      when DURATION_IN_MS BETWEEN 120001 AND 125000 THEN '120001-125000'
      else 'OTHERS'
  END AS grp, 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
from tab1
GROUP BY grp
```

Like ysth said in comments, separate the ranges.

The case statement defines the categories as `grp`, we `GROUP BY` this and the amount `count(*)` is per group.

Comment: I'm guessing they want the range calculated, not to use hard-coded ranges.  They may also want result rows for ranges where there are no records.  But I wasn't even going to attempt to get answers to any of that until I know for sure if this is sql server or mysql 8 or mysql pre-8 or mariadb.

Comment: Agree. This was too much a preemptive answer, and I didn't even notice the image url when I wrote this.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for the answers. It is on a sql server and i would like to not use hard codes ranges for sure. However, i dont know how to do it. The select case is the only solution i came up with for now. 

When i try to group it as danblack mentioned i get a error message saying that grp is a invalid column name.

Comment: If you tag an answer with mysql, you get a mysql answer. Tag appropriately and provide sufficient information in the question for an answer to be adequately verified.

Answer (score 0):

See if you like this technique:

```
SELECT
    FLOOR(DURATION_IN_MS / 5000)     * 5000     AS 'bucket start',
    FLOOR(DURATION_IN_MS / 5000 + 1) * 5000 - 1 AS 'bucket end',
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM MACHINE_PROCESSING_DURATION_EVALUATION
WHERE ...
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

It does not match your question exactly but is more flexible in because it automatically creates all the necessary ranges.  (Not `WITH` is needed.)

To get an "other", I might `UNION` with another query that inverts it.  (This is messier.)